# Android Xml Programming, poisition buttons on the availble space depending on the size

Tags: android, xml, image, position, percentage

I've runned into a small problem, I want to create buttons that are positioned on a certain part of an image.

My original though was using an image as an background for my LinearLayout and place the buttons on top of the map. I could position them the way I wanted to by changing the margins, however I ran into a problem when the screen size changed.

Source code:

```
<LinearLayout  android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/howlingabyssmap"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/health"
        android:src="@drawable/health"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone now of a way to solve this? I tried using weightSum and layout_weight, but I didn't manage to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Buttons and ImageView inside a FrameLayout instead of using LinearLayout and ImageButton

Comment: It didn't work. As soon as the screen size changed the button jumped around. I want it to stay on the same position in the image, even when the screen size changes